# why ansible set_fact list result include many // //

Tags: ansible

```
    - name: some files
      shell: ls | egrep "{{ item }}" chdir={{ log_path }}
      register: upload_files
      with_items:
        - type1
        - type2
      failed_when: upload_files.rc != 1 and upload_files.rc != 0

    - set_fact: files_list="{% set output = [] %}\
          {% for x in (upload_files.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines')) %}\
            {% for y in x %}\
              {% if y %}\
                {{ output.append(y) }}\
              {% endif %}\
            {% endfor %}\
          {% endfor %}\
          {{ output }}"
    - debug: var=files_list
```

the playbook result has many \, I won't know how it happens and how to resolve

```
"\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ [u'type1.log', u'type2.log', u'type1.log']"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *The playbook result has many \, I don't know how it happens

A: The behavior of "\" is different between YAML and JSON. For example

```sh
    - debug:
        msg: "abc\
              def"
```

```sh
    - debug: msg="abc\
                  def"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: abcdef

  msg: abc\ def
```

> Q: *How to resolve?*

A: Use YAML format

---

But, the solution can be a simpler assignment. The filter *flatten* can be useful. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        files_list: "{{ upload_files.results|
                        map(attribute='stdout_lines')|
                        flatten }}"
```

In Python3, if you decide to omit the filter *flatten* replace it with *list* because of *map* returns an *iterator* only.  For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        files_list: "{{ upload_files.results|
                        map(attribute='stdout_lines')|
                        list }}"
```

Comment: Your answer is useful to me, but in my case， the result is a nested list. The following method is more in line with expectations`files_list="{{ upload_files.results| map(attribute='stdout_lines')| list |sum(start=[]) }}"`

Comment: Glad to hear the expectations were clarified.